# Pandas read_html ignoring some decimal commas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Having a html with this table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32.412,18 | 57,77 | 3,25ml |
| 2.345,44 | 42,34 | 4,55ml |
| 2.111,44 | 31,51 | 5,12ml |

I'm using pandas **read_html** to read it like a dataframe. But I'm getting an unexpected result as column B decimal comma is being ignored:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32.412,18 | 5777 | 3,25ml |
| 2.345,44 | 4234 | 4,55ml |
| 2.111,44 | 3151 | 5,12ml |

I also tried adding thousands='.', decimal=',' but still not working as expected.

What am I missing? I am using pandas 1.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `thousands` with `None` or `''`(empty string)

```py
df = pd.read_html('test.html', thousands=None)[0]
```

```
print(df)

           A      B       C
0  32.412,18  57,77  3,25ml
1   2.345,44  42,34  4,55ml
2   2.111,44  31,51  5,12ml
```